# How to make the plot not disappear?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose you need to store the `figure` and `subplot` in variables (to later modify attributes). How can you make the whole figure to stay and not quickly disappear after some millisecs?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure() 

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax.plot(1)

fig.show()
```

Comment: What does "Easy: `plt.show()`" mean? Is it the answer to your question?

Comment: Yeah! For some reason I changed `plt` to `fig`. I think to keep the question. It can be tricky to find out, since both objects support `show()`.

Comment: In that case, you should answer the question yourself (and accept after 24 hours)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change `fig` to `plt`:

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: For me if you have `#plt.ion()   # interactive mode, careful with uncommenting, things will dissapear` things disappear. Careful!